# Detect walls or planar surfaces (with OpenCV)?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, augmented-reality

I'm developing a simple app that analyses video stream from iOS camera, detects walls or planar surfaces and project an image on it. In my case I can't use markers. What OpenCV algorithm should I use? Or maybe there is another library that would do the job?

I find PTAM (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBI5HwitBX4) is doing what I need but I can't find a working code yet and all the resources look dead. I spent a month now on it and start hitting a wall, I would be happy if someone just pointed me to the right direction, please!

Comment: I don't think the PTAM link you've provided detects 'planar' surfaces. In fact, just the opposite because you can see there are no detected points on a plains like the desk surface... they are detecting the corners/changes etc... not walls or planars...

Comment: and they are using the FORCE to move Vader... so no documentation available for that of course ... :P

Comment: Thanks for your comment @lukya. Yes, what I liked about PTAM is that it detects corners, converts it to 3D space and detects "planar surface" where these corners/features are located. It is exactly this functionality I'm looking for. I also found visual SLAM that basically is doing similar things, but the company (13thlab.com) was acquired by Facebook/Oculus and everything got "classified". Heh..

Answer (score 1):

You can check the opencv example.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dd/dd4/tutorial_detection_of_planar_objects.html

It finds plane and its corresponding Homographic matrix by matched feature points.